# How to substract group by total in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

[image]
**In this Image I have three groups, the grand child group is pp
 and this will always have two values 1 and 2 between these group there will be multiple rows for pp=1 and pp=2  now i have to substract pp=2 QTY total from pp=1 Total Please help me. on the last of group as grand total.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!pp.Value = 1,Fields!IssueQty.Value,0) -
SUM(IIF(Fields!pp.Value = 2,Fields!IssueQty.Value,0)
```

The expression must be in the scope of the `details` or `pp` group.

Let me know if this helps.